# analysing SVM regression result

Tags: python, svm

I have used SVM regression for the prediction of rainfall.The rainfall in the month of JAN to DEC is taken as x and annual rainfall as y.A 80:20 split is used to split train and test data.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
    clf = SVR(gamma='auto', C=0.1, epsilon=0.2)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train) 
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred))
    print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))
    time_taken = time.time()-t0
    print('Time taken', time_taken)
    df_SVR = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})
    print(df_SVR)
```

When executed the code ,I got a score of 412.72 RMSE. And in each case the prediction value is the case.
[image]

Why am I getting a large RMSE and why all the predicted value are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't really understand why you chose `gamma='auto'` as one of your hyper-parameter, but if you get rid of it and let the model decide which gamma will be used may have a better performance.

And, the small C and small epsilon may work on a contradicted way, so I think it is a good idea to balance this two hyper-parameters.

Here, I have made some random data trying to figure out the how to deal with it, hoping that it may help you with your problem.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR

# make data
month_rain = np.random.randint(1000, 5000, size=(10,12))
X = month_rain
y = np.random.randint(3000, 4000, size=(10,1))

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

svm_reg = SVR(gamma='auto', C=0.1, epsilon=0.2) # original model
svm_reg2 = SVR(C=0.1, epsilon=0.2) # get rid of gamma
svm_reg3 = SVR(C=100, epsilon=0.2) # get rid of gamma and use larger C
svm_reg4 = SVR(gamma='auto', C=100, epsilon=0.2) # use larger C

svm_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
svm_reg2.fit(X_train, y_train)
svm_reg3.fit(X_train, y_train)
svm_reg4.fit(X_train, y_train)

# check out the model score in the training dataset.
print(svm_reg.score(X_train, y_train))
print(svm_reg2.score(X_train, y_train))
print(svm_reg3.score(X_train, y_train))
print(svm_reg4.score(X_train, y_train))

# check out the result.
y_pred = svm_reg.predict(X_test)
y_pred2 = svm_reg2.predict(X_test)
y_pred3 = svm_reg3.predict(X_test)
y_pred4 = svm_reg4.predict(X_test)
print(y_test)
print(y_pred.reshape(-1,1))
print(y_pred2.reshape(-1,1))
print(y_pred3.reshape(-1,1))
print(y_pred4.reshape(-1,1))
```

Output:

```
score:
-0.05514476528005918
-0.055253731765687375
0.40714376538337693
0.47055666976833854

result:
origin:
[[3690]
 [3355]
 [3916]]

model 1:
[[3346.]
 [3346.]
 [3346.]]

model 2:
[[3345.95909456]
 [3345.99648151]
 [3345.933001  ]]

model 3:
[[3305.09456122]
 [3342.48150808]
 [3279.00100083]]

model 4:
[[3346.]
 [3346.]
 [3346.]]
```

Thus, I recommend you using a larger C to constrain your model, and it would have a better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Inputs samples need feature scaling, like minmax scaler, std scaler, before feeding into the training algorithm.
maybe the magnitude of different features varies a lot for your input.